# Follow Company issue (LinkedIn API)

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to follow a company without success.

I have generated an access token for all scopes which also works for other functions with the API:

**scope=w_messages+rw_company_admin+rw_nus+r_emailaddress+r_basicprofile+rw_groups+r_fullprofile+r_network+r_contactinfo**

The below code reaches the end and shows the MessageBox with message:
**"BadRequest,Can not parse JSON company document.\nRequest body:\n\nError:\nnull"**

I will be happy for help. I  have follwed the below documentation but it doesn't exactly show how to follow the company, so it leaves me with this question and example below:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-follow-and-suggestions

```
        String companyID = "9288340";
        requestUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies/id=" + companyID + "?oauth2_access_token=MYTOKENGOESHERE";

        RestSharp.RestClient rc = new RestSharp.RestClient();
        RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(requestUrl, RestSharp.Method.POST); //POST = Follow
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "json");

        request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;

        RestSharp.RestResponse restResponse = (RestSharp.RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
        RestSharp.ResponseStatus responseStatus = restResponse.ResponseStatus;

        MessageBox.Show(restResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + "," + restResponse.Content.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, I just managed to be able to follow a company.
So the below code is working:

```
    requestUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies?oauth2_access_token=MYTOKENGOESHERE";

                        var BODY = new
                        {
                            id = "9288340" //companyID 
                        };


    RestSharp.RestClient rc = new RestSharp.RestClient();
    RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest(requestUrl, RestSharp.Method.POST); //POST = Follow
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "json");

                        request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
                        request.AddBody(BODY);


    RestSharp.RestResponse restResponse = (RestSharp.RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
    RestSharp.ResponseStatus responseStatus = restResponse.ResponseStatus;

    MessageBox.Show(restResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + "," + restResponse.Content.ToString());
```